# subscribe notification characteristics linux/ios

Tags: ios, c, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I am trying to write a simple Gatt `peripheral` on linux device. I am currently able to see my service thanks to btgatt-client binary. I can read/write characteristics, enable notification, etc... I am using API from src/shared/gatt-db.h from `bluez5`, inspiration comes from tools/btgatt-server.c

However I am not able to make it work with my ios application without success. The subscription to notification failed. This ios application is able to work with a CC2541 bluetooth device so this is not an issue in ios side.

To enable the notification subscription I put some changes on the property value in the creation of the characteristics function like this :

```
gatt_db_service_add_characteristic(service, &uuid,
BT_ATT_PERM_READ | BT_ATT_PERM_WRITE,
BT_GATT_CHRC_PROP_READ | BT_GATT_CHRC_PROP_NOTIFY
signal_live_read_cb,
signal_live_write_cb,
server);
```

Do I forget to call some specific code to make it work correctly ?